# What is the process for saving erlang values to a file and loading them back?

Tags: erlang

For example I have a list I want to save as a file that has a lot of other erlang types. Then I want to load it back into a process What would I use? `io_lib:format("~P", [Term])` with `io:write` and then `file:consult`?

Comment: Btw, it is possible (maybe even normal?) to [write an inverse function to `file:consult/1`](http://zxq9.com/archives/1021). It is slightly annoying that this is not simply included in the file module, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to legoscia's solution, you can also write the result of `erlang:term_to_binary/1` to a file and read it back with `erlang:binary_to_term/1`. There's a few caveats with this approach, though:

1. The file will not be human-readable (at least not easily)
2. You can't store multiple terms easily because `erlang:term_to_binary/1` can produce null-characters and newlines, which can create problems with parsing. There are a few ways to get around this, though:

   - base64 encode the terms and separate by newline
   - store your terms inside of another term. For instance, if you have three terms you want to store, use `erlang:term_to_binary({T1, T2, T3})`
3. There's no handy `file:consult` equivalent for `term_to_binary`, so you have to explicitly read (as a binary) and then run `binary_to_term`

So why would you bother with `erlang:term_to_binary/1` at all? Two reasons:

1. Space efficiency (in most cases)
2. Parsing-speed (faster to parse `term_to_binary` than a human-readable term)

Comment: Besides, you could use `erlang:term_to_binary/2` and pass [compressed] as second argument for gzip compression.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Note that you need a trailing dot for each term, and that `file:consult` returns a list of all dot-terminated terms in the file.  So if you only have one term, the code would look like:

```
ok = file:write_file("myfile", io_lib:format("~p.~n", [Term])),
{ok, [Term]} = file:consult("myfile").
```